# How to sort columns in Grails view

Tags: sorting, grails

In the index method, I list records for a particular player.

e.g.

```
def index() {
    Player player = Player.get( params.playerId)
    def records = Record.findAllByPlayer(player, params:params)

    [records: records,  playerInstance: player, params: params]
}
```

This works, but none of the sortable columns work in the view.

How do I look up which column I need to sort, and how to I then use this information in findAllByXXX? I have scoured Google but have not found any examples which don't involve the simple "Books.list(params)" pattern.

In the view, I have sortableColumns:

```
<g:sortableColumn property="createdAt" title="${message(code: 'paymentRecord.created.label', default: 'Created at')} "
                  params="${params}" style="width: 15%;"/>
```

and I see the parameters at the end of the URL, e.g.:

```
 /index/1?sort=credit&order=desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination and sorting parameters which are available on [list](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html) method can also be used with dynamic finders.

So you can do it like this, if you have sort and order available in params.

```
Record.findAllByPlayer(player, params)
```

Or

```
Record.findAllByPlayer(player, [max: xx, offset: xx, sort: "name", order: "desc"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `Record.findAllByPlayer(player, params)` instead of `Record.findAllByPlayer(player, params:params)`.

You can see examples [here in grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html). One example from the documentation is

```
def results = Book.findAllByTitle("The Shining",
              [max: 10, sort: "title", order: "desc", offset: 100])
```